# Excel 2010 User Defined Function that returns a result BUT Also sets Cell Comments Crashes Excel when User clicks Fx

Tags: vba, excel, udf

We have a User Defined VBA Function. This function returns a result, but also sets the comment of the cell. It works, we get the result and the comment is set.

We have included user Help on this function.
However, if the user clicks on the Fx to get Help, Excel crashes. If we comment out the setting of the cell comment, the help works. 
Including **`"On Error"`** didn't solve the problem.

We suspect the problem is that when Excel is running the function from the "Fx" Help that it can't set the cell comment -- because effectively there is no cell.

Is there a Flag in Excel that we can use to detect that Excel is running the function from the "Fx" help screen and skip setting the comments?

Any other ideas are welcome.

Code to set comment which is called by our UDF:

```
Sub SetRangeComment(rng As Range, comment As String, intHeight As Long, intWidth As Long)

    On Error GoTo IgnoreError

    rng.ClearComments
    rng.AddComment comment
    If intHeight > 0 Then
        rng.comment.Shape.height = 13 * intHeight
    End If
    If intWidth > 0 Then
'    rng.comment.Shape.width = 6 * intWidth
    End If
    Exit Sub

IgnoreError:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `application.caller` But what do you mean crashes? Does it error? What if you step through the code, where does it crash?

Comment: TypeName(Application.Caller) is "Range" in both the case of calling the function from the cell or by clicking on the Fx.

Comment: It fails in a mode in which Excel brings up a message box asking if I want to debug Excel code using Visual Studio. it is failing on the rng.ClearComments. Although this works fine when called by the cell, I'm sure that the issue is the Fx form that is present, doesn't have comments that can be set.  I need a way to detect that the Fx form is open. Then I can skip the comment setting. Any ideas of how to detect this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Public Function MyUdf()
    MsgBox TypeName(Application.Caller)
    MyUdf = "X"
End Function
```

But creating Comments with a UDF is not recommended.